# scikit-learn: clustering text documents using DBSCAN

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, data-mining, dbscan

I'm tryin to use scikit-learn to cluster text documents. On the whole, I find my way around, but I have my problems with specific issues. Most of the examples I found illustrate clustering using scikit-learn with k-means as clustering algorithm. Adopting these example with k-means to my setting works in principle. However, k-means is not suitable since I don't know the number of clusters. From what I read so far -- please correct me here if needed -- DBSCAN or MeanShift seem the be more appropriate in my case. The scikit-learn website provides examples for each cluster algorithm. The problem is now, that with both DBSCAN and MeanShift I get errors I cannot comprehend, let alone solve.

My minimal code is as follows:

```
docs = []
for item in [database]:
    docs.append(item)

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(docs)

X = X.todense() # <-- This line was needed to resolve the isse

db = DBSCAN(eps=0.3, min_samples=10).fit(X)
...
```

(My documents are already processed, i.e., stopwords have been removed and an Porter Stemmer has been applied.)

When I run this code, I get the following error when instatiating DBSCAN and calling `fit()`:

```
...
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/cluster/dbscan_.py", line 248, in fit
clust = dbscan(X, **self.get_params())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/cluster/dbscan_.py", line 86, in dbscan
n = X.shape[0]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Clicking on the line in `dbscan_.py` that throws the error, I noticed the following line

```
...
X = np.asarray(X)
n = X.shape[0]
...
```

When I use these to lines directly in my code for testing, I get the same error. I don't really know what `np.asarray(X)` is doing here, but after the command `X.shape = ()`. Hence `X.shape[0]` bombs -- before, `X.shape[0]` correctly refers to the number of documents. Out of curiosity, I removed `X = np.asarray(X)` from `dbscan_.py`. When I do this, something is computing heavily. But after some seconds, I get another error:

```
...
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csr.py", line 214, in extractor
(min_indx,max_indx) = check_bounds(indices,N)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csr.py", line 198, in check_bounds
max_indx = indices.max()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 17, in _amax
out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity
```

In short, I have no clue how to get DBSCAN working, or what I might have missed, in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *implementation in sklearn* seems to assume you are dealing with a finite vector space, and wants to find the *dimensionality* of your data set. Text data is commonly represented as *sparse* vectors, but now with the same dimensionality.

Your input data probably isn't a data matrix, but the sklearn implementations needs them to be one.

You'll need to find a different implementation. Maybe try the implementation in [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/), which is very fast, and should not have this limitation.

You'll need to spend some time in understanding similarity first. For DBSCAN, you *must* choose `epsilon` in a way that makes sense for your data. There is no rule of thumb; this is domain specific. Therefore, you first need to figure out which similarity threshold means that two documents are similar.

Mean Shift may actually *need* your data to be vector space of fixed dimensionality.

Comment: Quoting Homer: "Uh huh. Uh huh. Okay. Um, can you repeat the part of the stuff where you said all about the...things? Uh... the things?" :). I just started to play around, trying to follow and understand the examples. To get things working, not worrying about the results at the moment. I just can't see the difference between my setting and the examples. `X.shape` tells mit it's a (832, 20932) matrix which reflects my 832 documents and 20k+ different terms. But you're right, of course, I need to get a better understanding. I will have a look at ELKI. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Short story: it's not a DBSCAN limitation, but it could be a scipy limitation.
If `np.asarray(X).shape` returns a tuple, then it should not fail as above. I don't use numpy enough to be able to tell you how to properly convert a sparse matrix into a dense matrix.

Comment: I found the problem: The expected format of matrix `X` differs between, e.g., k-means and DBSCAN. While both expect a (n_sample, n_features) matrix, k-means expects a spare matrix, DBSCAN a dense matrix. Thus, if I add `X=X.todense()` before calling `fit(X)`, it works.

Comment: That is essentially what I'm trying to say. Except that technically **DBSCAN does not need a dense matrix**. It's the sklearn version that does, for a reason unknown to me.

Comment: Yeah, I had to get used the whole numpy matrix notions. The sklearn documentation is not intuitive without the required insights into numpy. Hence my problems. Thanks a lot for your help, I will mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 15):

It looks like sparse representations for DBSCAN are supported [as of Jan. 2015](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/494b8e574337e510bcb6fd0c941e390371ef1879).

I upgraded sklearn to 0.16.1 and it worked for me on text.