# Clustering of news articles

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, cluster-analysis, information-retrieval, unsupervised-learning

My scenario is pretty straightforwrd: I have a bunch of news articles (~1k at the moment) for which I know that some cover the same story/topic. I now would like to group these articles based on shared story/topic, i.e., based on their similarity.

What I did so far is to apply basic NLP techniques including stopword removal and stemming. I also calculated the tf-idf vector for each article, and with this can also calculate the, e.g., cosine similarity based on these tf-idf-vectors. But now with the grouping of the articles I struggles a bit. I see two principle ways -- probably related -- to do it:

1) Machine Learning / Clustering: I already played a bit with existing clustering libraries, with more or less success; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25217065/scikit-learn-clustering-text-documents-using-dbscan). On the one hand, algorithms such as k-means require the number of clusters as input, which I don't know. Other algorithms require parameters that are also not intuitive to specify (for me that is).

2) Graph algorithms: I can represent my data as a graph with the articles being the nodes and weighted adges representing the pairwise (cosine) similarity between the articles. With that, for example, I can first remove all edges that fall below a certain threshold and then might apply graph algorithms to look for strongly-connected subgraphs.

In short, I'm not sure where best to go from here -- I'm still pretty new in this area. I wonder if there some best practices for that, or some kind of guidelines which methods / algorithms can (not) be applied in certain scenarios.

(EDIT: forgot to link to related question of mine)

Comment: I don't think there's a single "best way" to perform this task; in fact, from the way you posed your question, you could potentially apply dozens of different algorithms and obtain qualitatively similar results. Did you read [any paper on text categorization](http://scholar.google.it/scholar?q=text+categorization)?

Comment: Yeah, I started reading about similarity measures, (unsupervised) learning / clustering, and related topics. But in parallel I would also like just to try some things out -- you know, "learning by doing" or if it happens "learning by burning/failing". I don't expect THE one best way to do. However it seems like a rather common task, and I was hoping for some best-practice approaches.

Comment: I really want to know how you clustering your dataset because I have a set of resumes that I want to cluster and categories them and am pretty new to the field how can I contact you sorry because I'm not answering here but you are my last hope *_* sorry again

Comment: @Abeerzaroor -- See this [StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25217065/scikit-learn-clustering-text-documents-using-dbscan) of mine with a minimal, now working example. It's essentially just a simplified version of the more elaborate example on the [SciKit-Learn website](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/document_clustering.html). Both links should help you to start rolling.

Answer (score 3):

Try the class of Hierarchical Agglomerative Clustering [HAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering) algorithms with Single and Complete linkage.

*These algorithms do not need the number of clusters as input.*

The basic principle is similar to growing a minimal spanning tree across a given set of data points and then stop based on a threshold criteria. A closely related class is the Divisive clustering algorithms which first builds up the minimal spanning tree and then prunes off a branch of the tree based on inter-cluster similarity ratios.

Comment: Debasis, I will look into that! Are there any off-the-shell tools or libraries I can use to some first ideas?

Comment: You can use Weka.. It has both the single link and the complete link implementations of HAC... http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/clusterers/HierarchicalClusterer.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also try a canopy variation on k-means to create a relatively quick estimate for the number of clusters (k).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canopy_clustering_algorithm

Will you be recomputing over time or do you only care about a static set of news?  I ask because your k may change a bit over time.

Comment: For the time being I just trying to play around with off-the-shell algorithms/libraries to get some idea how stuff works and what results to expect. But you're right, in the long run the set of documents will be dynamic. I already started reading about incremental solutions of clustering algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can model your dataset as a graph you could apply stochastic clustering based on markov models. Here are link for resources on MCL algorithm:

[Official thesis description and code base](http://micans.org/mcl/)

[Gephi plugin for MCL (to experiment and evaluate the method)](https://gephi.org/plugins/#/plugin/markov-cluster-algorithm-mcl)

Comment: This look pretty interesting, thanks! I installed the Gephi plugin and applied it on some sample data.

Comment: Christian, I'd be interested in knowing more about your experiment and results with graph-based approaches and otherwise.